# mongomapper geospatial 'within' query

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongomapper

I'm trying to do a 'within' query using mongomapper.  When I execute the command in the shell everything works fine:

```
box = [[32.476750,-117.246094],[32.850173,-116.806641]]
db.locations.find({"location" : {"$within" : {"$box" : box}}})
// Bunch of results
```

However, when I run the same in the rails console I get nil:

```
box = [[32.476750,-117.246094],[32.850173,-116.806641]]
Location.find(:location => {"$within" => {"$box" => box}})
 => nil
```

If I do Location.first I get a location back so I do know that I'm pointing at the correct db collection.  What am I doing wrong with my mongomapper query that's returning 0 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out.  Instead of using 'find' I used 'where' instead.  Now I'm getting the correct result set back.