# mongoose within box geo-spatial query does not work correctly

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongoose, bounding-box, mongodb-query

Simple question:
what is the proper way of making a geo-spatial query with mongoose on nodejs?

Complex story:
I created a Schema with mongoose with a spatial index

```
var MySchema = newSchema({
// skipped ...
    location : {
        type : [ Number ],
        required : true,
        index : '2d'
    },
// skipped ...
});
```

Then I inserted into the table 3 documents. 
I can retrieve these documents with both mongo client and mongoose
using `db.mymodels.find({})` and `MyModel.find({});`

Now I try to make a geo-spatial query with a bounding box.
mongo client works ok

```
db.mymodels.find({location: {$within: {$box: box}}})
```

returns only one result as expected, within the box.
Mongoose on the other hand, returns back all three results

```
query = MyModel.where({location: {$within : {$box : box}}});
query.run(cb)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853666/mongomapper-geospatial-within-query) says you should use find() instead of where, 
but when I tried replacing find with where, I got an error `'need an area > 0'`
I checked, my bounding box is formatted correctly, lower-left then upper-right.

What to do?
What is the proper way to make a geo-spatial query with a bounding box using mongoose?

Comment: What does your generated query look like?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how do I print out the generated query?

Comment: Ah, I thought you're using rails. With node, I don't know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you use `find()` or `where()`.

Would you mind posting what mongoose is sending to the db by enabling logging and checking your console: `mongoose.set('debug', true)`

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you! I've noticed that my coordinate array consists of strings instead of  numbers '78.0' instead of 78, I didn't notice it during usual debug,  only now with your suggestion!

Comment: I use node-inspector, which debugs nodejs server-apps using chrome's developer tools, I just noticed that numbers are shown in blue while strings in red, but strings don't have any ' or " chars around them. Damn it!